# How to run spring boot project with multiple main classes

Tags: java, spring-boot, program-entry-point

I have a spring boot project with 3 main classes

```
com.abc.test --> Application
com.abc.test.pqr  --> ApplicationMain2
com.abc.test.xyz  --> ApplicationMain3
```

Now spring boot project is unable to build so I have given POM entry as

```
<properties>
        <start-class>com.abc.test.Application</start-class>
</properties>
```

From eclipse I am able to run all 3 Main successfully and create a jar.
But whenever I am trying to run jar with command its running Application class.

```
java -jar -Dloader.main=com.abc.test.pqr.ApplicationMain2 test-1.0.jar
```

With following commands giving error of class not found

```
java -cp test-1.0.jar -Dloader.main=com.abc.test.pqr.ApplicationMain2 
java -cp -Dloader.main=com.abc.test.pqr.ApplicationMain2 test-1.0.jar com.abc.test.pqr.ApplicationMain2
java -classpath test-1.0.jar com.abc.test.pqr.ApplicationMain2
```

Comment: `From eclipse I am able to run all 3 Main successfully and create a jar` and all are running on the same port normally?

Comment: From eclipse, are you running all 3 main classes as Java applications or as a Spring Boot Application?

Comment: Please see: 
https://dzone.com/articles/configuring-a-main-class-in-spring-boot#:~:text=Spring%20Boot%20allows%20us%20to,have%20to%20configure%20the%20POM.&text=We%20can%20define%20any%20of%20the%20main%20classes%20in%20the%20configuration.

Comment: @Ashish Thank you sir. I forgot to add property launcher command.

Comment: @Qwer Izuken Thats a  really good point. but I am not running all three processes parallely. Its simply 3 projects I have packaged in 1 jar and I will use only 1 at a time. Anyway Thank you for response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot Ashish
Command I used to run was

```
java -cp test-1.0.jar -Dloader.main=com.abc.test.pqr.ApplicationMain2
```

**The problem is we are not including PropertiesLauncher.** Along with class we are also required to give path of property launcher explicitly. So correct command is as below

```
java -cp test-1.0.jar -Dloader.main=com.abc.test.pqr.ApplicationMain2 org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher
```